# Find Exchange mailboxes that are forwarded to a Distribution List

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

Trying to figure out a way to find all the mailboxes that are forwarded to a Distribution List.

No luck with this, any one has better idea?

```
$group=Get-DistributionGroup | select PrimarySmtpAddress
Get-Mailbox  | Where-Object { $_.ForwardingAddress -eq "$group" } | Select-Object Name,ForwardingAddress
```

Comment: pretty sure you need to just need to drop the `""` off of `"$group"`, and possibly need to select the `.name` parameter of that object, but is [Get-DistributionGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996367(v=exchg.160).aspx) not suitable for this task?

Comment: same with that too

Comment: oh wait I see, $group is an array, would need to make several changes to get that to work, which unfortunately I don't have the extra time for ATM, did you give `Get-DistributionGroupMember` a shot?

Comment: it gives name, smtp etc

Answer (score 1):

Untested (PSv2+; PSv3+ would allow for simpler syntax):

```
$groupEmailAddresses = Get-DistributionGroup | foreach { $_.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString() }
Get-Mailbox  | where { $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress -and 
                    $groupEmailAddresses -contains $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress.ToString() } | 
  Select-Object Name, ForwardingSmtpAddress
```

Note that while many PowerShell operators can operate on *arrays* (collections),

- the array must be on the *LHS* (left-hand side)
- and the RHS (right-hand side) must be a *scalar* (a non-collection value)

In the case at hand, `-contains` tells us whether the collection on the LHS has the single RHS value among its elements.

Comment: No result empty :(

Comment: @Owl: Since I don't have access to these cmdlets, I can't investigate on my own. Replace everything starting with  `| where ...` with `| % { if ($_.ForwardingSmtpAddress) { $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress.ToString() } }` and see if you (a) get email addresses at all, and (b) if they're in the same format as the ones in `$groupEmailAddresses`.